# How do I write to a closed zip folder in a function?

Tags: python, json, compression, zip

I want to write a json file to a zip folder that's in a function
The issue is: at the end of the function I must close the zip so when I re-run the function and save another json to it it won't save as its closed.
I'm super beginner can anyone give some direction/guidance?

```
def ExportJson(files):

    now = datetime.now()
    now_date = now.strftime("%d%m%y")

    # new json name
    new_json_name = now_date + new_fname + ".json"

    # saves dataframe to json
    files.to_json(new_json_name)

    # new zip file name
    new_zip_name = work_dir + "/" + new_fname + ".zip"

    # Create new zip file
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(new_zip_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    # Write json to zip
    zip_file.write(new_json_name)
    zip_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def export_json(files):
    now = datetime.now()
    now_date = now.strftime("%d%m%y")
    new_fname = 'temp' + now_date

    # new json name
    new_json_name = new_fname + ".json"

    # new zip file name
    new_zip_name = new_fname + ".zip"

    with zipfile.ZipFile(new_zip_name, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as myzip:
        myzip.writestr(new_json_name, files.to_json())
```